# why OpenErp create some default field in postgresql database tables

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

Can any one explain  me why OpenErp Create some  default in posgresql database table 
while creating a new object in OpneErp module ??

In a **email_template module** -->
*email.template* object --> create 
some default field 
like..

```
id, create_uid, create_date, write_date
```

explain each field with description

While from Openerp trunk-Server in *base module* like..

```
 res_users and res_partner
```

doesn't created this kind of field in PostgreSQL database table

my question is why create default field and and why not default field in some base module ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **double check** following field are already exist in base module table `res_users` and `res_partner`

```
id, create_uid, create_date, write_date, write_uid
```

Reason behind this whenever you create new table you must inherit `osv.osv` base class.

> Example: I'm create *project* table and inherit from `osv.osv` so this table automatically create extra five column **id, create_uid, create_date, write_date, write_uid** plus you define **project_name** column. Total 6 six column created.

#### project.py

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields

class My_project(osv.osv):
    _name = 'my.project'
    _description = 'My project'
    _columns = {
         'project_name':fields.char('Project Name',size=30),
    }
```

#### Advantage

1. To know which user are create this table with timestamp (date time).
2. Auto Increment of ID field. so this column primary key,
3. Which user (write_uid) are update table row with also store with timestamp update into `write_date` column.

   So above reason help us to track *time* and *userid*.

---

If you set **_log_access = False** Attributes four fields will not be created in the SQL table: **create_uid, create_date, write_uid, write_date**.

#### project.py

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields

class My_project(osv.osv):
    _name = 'my.project'
    _description = 'My project'
    _log_access = False
    _columns = {
         'project_name':fields.char('Project Name',size=30),
    }
```

Now you check only 2 column are create for this table.

Hope this help you!

Comment: well and fine dear..!!

Answer (score 2):

You must please verify your database package, the following fields are already there in `res_users` and `res_partners`.

and the fields:

- `id`:  the sequences of index numbers for each record of particular
  table.
- `create_uid`: the user id who created a particular record.
- `create_date`: creation date of record.
- `write_uid`: the user id who last update a particular record
- `write_date`: date of record updated

Comment: its ok my mistake for that ya its create a fields